# Aurelia: How to trigger click immediately after blur

Tags: event-handling, dom-events, aurelia

I have a table with the Aurelia structure as follows:

```
//app.ts

products = [{
    name: "book",
    options: [{
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }, {
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }, {
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }]
    }, {
    name: "notebook",
    options: [{
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }, {
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }, {
        prop1: value1,
        prop2: value2
    }]
    }, {..and so on}];


selectProduct(product) {
    this.selectedProduct = product;
}

saveOption(option) {
    // save the edited option value in the database
}

// app.html

<tr repeat.for="product of products">
    <td click.trigger="selectProduct(product)">${product.name}<td>
    <td repeat.for="option of product.options">
        <input type="text" value.bind="option.prop2" blur.trigger="saveOption(option)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what the actual table in my original app looks like, the above code is a simplified version of the table. [table](https://postimg.org/image/adzpyh4sp/)

Basically, I want to enable the user to be able to do following:

- edit any cell in any row, and on cell blur, it saves the edited value in the database.
- click on the first column of any row, which is the product name, to select  and highlight that particular row.

**It works fine, except for the following use case**:

- User edits a cell in any row, and **immediately** clicks on the first column `name` (any row, not necessarily the edited row).

  Ideally, it is supposed to save the edited value and select that particular row(the row whose name was clicked after editing, not necessarily the edited row) at the same time. (`blur` triggering the `saveOption(option)` and clicking on `name` triggering the `selectProduct(product)`).

But what is happening is, it triggers `saveOption(option)` on `blur`, but does not trigger `selectProduct(product)`, somehow the `blur` event is preventing the `click` event.

Am I missing something, or is there a cleaner way to achieve two event calls simultaneously? Thanks.

Comment: You should post an example here of what you mean - https://gist.run/?id=883568d7c8e2add9ed393150100f4744 - you can repro in gist.run

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the product to the `saveOption` method, and call `selectProduct` at the end of `saveOption`

```js
selectProduct(product) {
    this.selectedProduct = product;
}

saveOption(option, product) {
    // save the edited option value in the database
    this.selectProduct(product);
}
```

```html
<tr repeat.for="product of products">
    <td click.trigger="selectProduct(product)">${product.name}<td>
    <td repeat.for="option of product.options">
        <input type="text" value.bind="option.prop2"   blur.trigger="saveOption(option, product)">
    </td>
</tr>
```